# $L_1$ boundedness does not imply uniform intrgrability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal H$ denote a family of random variables on ($\Omega,\mathcal A ,P$) .We all know that $\mathcal H$ is uniformly integrable implies $\mathcal H$ is $L_1$ bounded but converse is not true. How can I gat an example for this and how can I prove that this is not uniformly integrable .

Comment: As usual scaling is our friend. Consider a smooth compactly supported function $f$ and then define $f_n(x)=n f(nx)$. We have $\Vert f_n \Vert_1=\Vert f \Vert_1$, but the family is not uniformly integrable unless $f=0$.

Comment: can you give a constractive example

Comment: That is what I just did. Can I be more constructive than that? You can also pick a function which is continuous and has compact support (and is not identically zero). I assume can find such a function yourself.

Comment: That the family is not uniformly integrable follows from the fact that if (for example) $f$ has support in $[0,1]$, then $f_n$ has support in $[0,1/n]$.